# LWC: Record Id format when chaining wired properties?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

The [Understanding Wire Service doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) says the following:

> You can use one @wire output as another @wire input. For example, you
>   could use `$record.data.fieldName` as an input to another wire adapter.

However, this `$record.data.fieldName` format doesn't work for me.  Instead, I have to use `$[theProperty].data.fields.[theFieldName].value`.  Here's my working code for pulling the contact record for a community user:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';

import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import USER_CONTACTID from '@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import CONTACT_FIRSTNAME from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import CONTACT_LASTNAME from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';

export default class MyComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: USER_ID, fields: [USER_CONTACTID]}) theUser;
    @wire(getRecord, {
            recordId: '$theUser.data.fields.ContactId.value', 
            fields: [CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, CONTACT_LASTNAME]
    }) theContact;

}
```

Whereas if I follow the documentation, this doesn't retrieve the contact:

```
@wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$theUser.data.ContactId', 
        fields: [CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, CONTACT_LASTNAME]
}) theContact;
```

Has anyone else run into this?  Am I misunderstanding the format to be used?

Comment: This might be a bug in the documentation! Checking internally to see how can this be fixed!

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, were you able to find out if this was a problem in the documentation?